# Epsilon delta proof; constraining delta.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

I've been trying to do some $\epsilon -\delta$ proofs, but I keep running into problems regarding certain steps. Namely, I can bring the proof to a point that is almost complete, but to complete it I would need to place a constraint on $\delta$ to make the next inequality true (such as $x^2+y^2≤\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ provided $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}≤1$).

If I had
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$$
Is it fine to constrain my $\delta$ (such as $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta<1$) because my limit is within the disc $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<1$?

If I come to a point where I would need to do that, have I done something wrong?

Is there some extra step that I should make that I am missing?

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

The short answer would be: **No**, you have done nothing wrong. And here's why:

The definition of limit says that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, **there exists a** $\delta > 0$, such that... etc. If you place any (extra) constraints on  what  $\delta$  may be, then nothing goes wrong. In your example you say you choose $0 < \delta < 1$ and then you get what you want. That's fine because that means a suitable $\delta > 0$ definitely **exists** and that's really all we need.

So yes, you may place any constraint on $\delta>0$ that you want.

N.B. Just make sure that you keep $\delta > 0$. So the constraint $\delta \le 0$, would not be fine for instance. This goes without saying, however.